# Windows 7: Set Physical Memory Limit

Tags: windows-7, process, virtual-memory, memory-limit

Where can we set the maximum physical memory an Application/Process can use. I am not trying set a cap on Maximum memory, rather the amount allowed on physical memory before switching to virtual memory.

Comment: Can I ask what your use case is? This seems like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378)... I mean, is the question you want to guarantee another program always has access to X RAM?

Comment: The idea is to reduce available memory to any application in general and see how it performs.

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment "The idea is to reduce available memory to any application in general and see how it performs. "

I suggest you use a virtual machine so you can run the application in that environment and easily control the about of resource it has.